# How do I print emails in Outlook 2013 with additional fields displayed?

Tags: printing, microsoft-outlook-2013

By default, Outlook 2013 prints emails with only the 'From', 'Sent', 'To' and 'Subject' fields in the header. How do I get it to display 'Received' (time email was received) also?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create something yourself using either VBA or creating an addin. Outlook does not provide easy access to the other fields in the UI but they are accessible from the object model.